# is it possible to set text at specific position on image label in java

Tags: java

I want to set database data on Image Label at specific position

```
dragLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
dragLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Your code has `dragLabel[i]` and `dragLabel`. If `dragLable` is a `JLabel[]` they should both be `dragLabel[i]`. If `dragLabel` is a `JLabel`, then they should both be `dragLabel`.

Comment: Sorry, actually both are dragLabel  but were written different mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

I found exact which i wanted...

Try this

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("Hi", 30, 10); //these are x and y positions
    g.drawString("jj", 30, 20);
}
```

};